# phpMyAdmin unable to connect to MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been using xampp 1.7.4 on a local installation php version is 5.3.5 for several years without any problems.  I develop Joomla! websites offline and then upload to the server.

My phpMyAdmin stopped working, giving this error message:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I am a complete dummy with servers and NEVER fiddle with settings I do not fully understand.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: u sure u provide correct password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go inside your phpMyAdmin directory inside XAMPP installation folder. There will be a file called config.inc.php. Inside that file, find this line:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; you must make sure that this field has your mysql root password (the one that you set).